# Converting text to bits (1's and 0's)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, hash

I'm implementing an MD-5 Hashing algorithm and I want to convert the text I have to bits so I can start manipulating them. As you know Hashing require taking block of bits and then manipulating them. There are many ways to do that but I can't determine the best/easiest way to just convert the text (string) into array of bits. Any clue ? In C#

Comment: MD5 is already implemented in dotnet - are you just experimenting/learning?

Comment: Yeah I have to do it as a project for a university course.

Comment: Morano, it is appreciated if you use the [homework] tag in such a case. CW was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding.GetBytes(string s) [see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx). Of course, you have to select a fitting encoding, depending on the encoding you want.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use the Encoding.GetBytes(string s) as suggested, you could then pass the byte[] to the constructor of the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2(v=VS.100).aspx) class:

> Manages a compact array of bit values, which are represented as Booleans, where true indicates that the bit is on (1) and false indicates the bit is off (0).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you were asking for.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = GetBits("0101010111010010101001010");
    }

    private bool[] GetBits(string sBits)
    {
        bool[] aBits = new bool[sBits.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < aBits.Length; i++)
        {
            aBits[i] = sBits[i] == '1';
        }

        return aBits;
    }
```